# The Witcher I - Cannot beat Grand Master

Tags: the-witcher

I'm stuck a little with my Witcher I walkthrough.
I play Witcher I (EE, 1.45.1280) with [FCR](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher/mods/237/?) mod installed and use the 4th difficulty (of total 6).
So I'm on the final fight and I really cannot do anything with it.

[Grand Master](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Jacques_de_Aldersberg) is pretty strong and also he has something near a dozen of [ifrits](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Ifrit) around him for help.

[image]

The first strategy is that I try to beat the Master himself. But with FCR he does not die fast. After a few seconds his ifrits start to attack me from all sides. Of course, Gerald dies.

The second strategy is to beat all the servants first. And it works fine except one detail - when I kill all servants game constantly crashes. When I kill all except one, but then start to attack the Master - the game crashes. All the time.

So literally I have to options: Gerald dies or game crashes.

Does anyone has suggestions for this battle? Or, maybe, a console command or something like that to skip it. I'm really desperate with it.

Comment: remove the mods maybe that will fix the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Uri Popov suggested I removed the mod.

After that the battle was extremely easy.